# Twitter Api Integration related

Tags: android, twitter

How can i use twitter api in android application? I am creating one apps on twitter so how can i use it? What to do for twitter apps? any suggestion on twitter api tutorial

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See This Its a good example for twitter . It will work for You.[here](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application)!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [this tutorial](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/1089/) for integrating Twitter in an Android application using the [JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php) library.